# e-junkie overwriting referral information

Tags: paypal, google-analytics

I'm setting up conversion tracking for a client who is selling an ebook. He's using e-junkie as a shopping cart provider so the sales funnel takes the user through about 4 different domains:

1. domain1.com: client's domain - GA tracking code is installed)
2. e-junkie.com: shopping cart - imposible to implement any tracking code
3. paypal.com: payment processor - imposible to implement any tracking code
4. fatfreecartpro.com: thank you page hosted by e-junkie - implemented cross domain tracking code + ecommerce tracking

I've installed the ecommerce tracking code on the thank you page and I'm seeing correct transaction data in GA, however, the referral for all transactions is e-junkie.com.

Here's how the tracking code on my thank you page looks like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-xxxxxxxx-x']);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker',true],['_setDomainName','fatfreecartpro.com'],['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
```

I have also tried adding:

```
_gaq.push(['_link', 'http://www.fatfreecartpro.com/ecom/rp.php']); return false;
```

As an onclick event to all the links from domain1.com pointing to the shopping cart.

Any idea how to prevent the referral from being overwritten in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it will appear as a new visit since the referrer is outside of the tracked domain.

With universal analytics, you can configure google analytics to ignore certain referrers. I don't believe this is an option with the classic profile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [setCampNOKey()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/methods/gaJSApiCampaignTracking#_gat.GA_Tracker_._setCampNOKey) method. This allows you to define a parameter, e.g.

```
_gaq.push(['_setCampNOKey', 'noo']);
```

which, when appended to the url will disregard campaign information (including referer) from that url. So when users are send back from ejunkie to your clients domain the url needs (in this example) ?&noo=1234 (or &noo=true or any other truthy value) appended - while you will learn nothing about the ejunkie site it will at least keep the campaign information in your transactions intact.

Comment: The thank you page is hosted on a 3rd party site as well, so there's no URL where to append this parameter...